# Solving Parabolic PDE using Matlab

Tags: pde, matlab, parabolic-pde

I have the following pde (Burger's equation)

for $\epsilon>0: u_t+u.u_x=\epsilon.u_{xx}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R},t>0$

and the initial condition: $u(x,0)=\phi(x)=1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)$.

I want first to solve it (using matlab) for the case $\epsilon=0$, which is a first pde, and then for $\epsilon=0.1$ and $ \epsilon=0.001$.

Comment: How do you want to solve it ? Finite difference ? Finite Volume ? Finite elements ?

Comment: Just finite difference

Comment: Hi, welcome to scicomp.stackexchange. To receive more help from the community you should report: what did you already try; what are the problem you find; what is your question (in the post I do not see it).

Comment: Well I never programmed sadly that’s why I’m asking